# Random generation problem

Tags: c#, random

I know this is such an old thing and I have searched like every website for an answer before I post this but I couldn't find a solution

I am using C# - Windows Forms

and I have this peice of code :

```
char[] options = { 'a', 'l', 'w' };
```

and I also have this function :

```
static Random rand = new Random();
    static char OptionPicker(char[] options)
    {
        rand = new Random();
        return options[rand.Next(0, 2)];
    }
```

my problem is that when I want to navigate through an array of chars
and execute the previous function on each of this array

I get the same option picked and it doesn't get randomed ?

can you tell me how to do it ?
Best Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Random generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528066/c-random-generation)

Comment: -1 because this is a 1000-times dupe and several dupes are in the Related list. Exact title matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `rand = new Random();` line, you're creating the same object twice. `rand.Next(0, 3)` is enough to generate new random numbers. Also make sure that your upper bound is '3' not '2' since it is exclusive.

```
static Random rand = new Random();
static char OptionPicker(char[] options)
{
    return options[rand.Next(0, 3)]; // 3 is exclusive so results will be 0,1,2 only.
}
```

Comment: Note that this(just like the OP) is obviously not threadsafe since `rand` is a static variable.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things. You need to either not recreate the Random object each time or recreate it with a different Seed Value (in my sample I only create it once and tie the seed value to to the present time/milliseconds.)

A you should range your select based on the actual length of the array, rather than hardcoding to 2..

Try this: (in a console app)

```
namespace SO_Console_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] options = { 'a', 'l', 'w' };
            Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(OptionPicker(options,rand).ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public static char OptionPicker(char[] options, Random rand)
        {
            return options[rand.Next(0, options.Length)];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new Random object each time.

get rid off

```
 rand = new Random();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `rand = new Random()` - re-creating it in quick succession as you are makes it give you the same value each time.